# Are regular 1:1 meetings really that important?

Tags: software-industry, management, meetings, people-management

Are regular 1:1 meetings really that important ?

I guess that for many people the answer is, of course. But I have been working for a Beijing local company for 11 years, managing a team around 10 engineers. We don't have regular monthly 1:1, not to mention weekly or bi-weekly. I had thought it was probably just us because before joining my current employer I used to work US-based companies and the regular 1:1 meeting is the standard practice.

But recently I watched this interesting video called ["5 crazy things about working for Tiktok"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNUrZFkHXlo), 1 of the 5 key differences between China and US tech company is 1:1 meeting is rare in tiktok.

[image: No weekly 1:1 meeting]

Check his tweets https://twitter.com/LucasOuYang/status/1493408428626100226 if you don't want to watch the video.

I guess the easy answer for that is "culture difference". But I hope to get answer more that. The fact that tiktok is so successful deserves a better answer than just it is "culture difference".

--- update ---

Before I asked the question I already know people may scorn the question but I got an surprised answer saying I "confusing causation and correlation. Nothing here provides evidence that TikTok is successful because it doesn't do 1:1 meetings"

That is not my point. What I saying is that TikTok is so successful that some of ingrained believes may not be the case, or at least deserver a deeper look. Another example is no unit test. I guess this would be another "shocking" fact. But I didn't mention "no unit test" because I want this question to focus on 1:1

Comment: Could you please summarise the points made in the video? Nobody wants to watch 15 minutes of content to get to the point.

Comment: "The fact that tiktok is so successful deserves a better answer than just it is "culture difference"." https://xkcd.com/552/

Comment: Oh I found the author's tweets explain those differences https://twitter.com/LucasOuYang/status/1493408428626100226

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I guess many people will just scorn the question and simply reply with "yes". But I still asked it.

Comment: TikTok's success likely has exactly zero to do with its office culture.  Uber became a success with an absolute dumpster fire of a work culture.

Answer (score 5):

[ For avoidance of doubt: none of this post is a comment on US/Western vs Chinese *people*; it is commentary on US/Western vs Chinese business models ]

The Twitter thread you have linked in a comment tells you what's really going on here:

> [Most differences we noticed between Chinese [vs] US tech were a side effect of labor cost, a trend of Chinese firms relying more on manpower](https://twitter.com/LucasOuYang/status/1493408433902477313)

and

> [Orgs are extremely flat at Tiktok, some managers manage 200+ reports](https://twitter.com/LucasOuYang/status/1493408436427522049)

The US/Western business model rely on a smaller number of more highly skilled people, while the Chinese model relies on a larger number of less highly skilled people. If you're managing 5-10 people, you can absolutely give up 30 minutes to them every couple of weeks to check in with them, see how they're doing, help work out what they need to do to get to the next step in their career and whatever else, and it's important to do this because you don't want them to leave - as a company, you've invested time and money in them and you want to keep that investment.

Now, if you're "managing" 200 people, you can't do any of that. I've deliberately put "managing" in scare quotes there because there's no way one person can do anything meaningful for 200 reports. But they don't have to, because the company views those workers as replaceable - if they leave, the company didn't really invest in them, just hire another one from the production line of applicants and move on. Does that business model work? Maybe. Is it anything I'd want to be involved with? Absolutely not.

> The fact that tiktok is so successful deserves a better answer than just it is "culture difference".

You are confusing causation and correlation. Nothing here provides evidence that TikTok is successful *because* it doesn't do 1:1 meetings; the lack of 1:1 meetings is just a necessary consequence of the business model they have chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I also need to point your "causation and correlation" is wrong to me. I did not say or indicate this at all that "TikTok is successful because it doesn't do 1:1 meetings" Where did you get this ?

Comment: What I saying is that TikTok is so successful that some of ingrained believes may not be the case, or at least deserver a deeper look. Another example is no unit test. I guess this be another "shocking" fact.

Comment: Updated my question. "The Twitter thread you have linked in a comment tells you what's really going on here". Of course I watched the video and read those tweets so I know that is his main point. But I still like to see other opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I once worked for a company where my immediate boss was thousands of miles away on an island in the Pacific Ocean. We met one on one once - when he was shutting down the office and gave me the opportunity to move to another office.

One on one meetings are for educating each other: manager helping educate a worker about what is expected from that worker, coaching on improvement, and giving feedback on that improvement AND educating the manager about what the worker is doing and perceiving. If there is no need to educate, then a one-on-one meeting is unnecessary and only using time that could be better spent on other activities. When a competent worker is clearly communicating with the manager via written reports, then such meetings are rarely needed.

A good alternative is to go out for a meal or have a drink with an employee and allow them to talk outside of the work environment. I've taken the other contractors or my subcontractors out for lunch (my dime) ever so often to talk over issues and what I saw happening so that they would not be surprised.

Comment: ”A good alternative is to go out for a meal or have a drink with an employee and allow them to talk outside of the work environment. “ That is what I do regularly. And I pay.